# SSL handshake fails in gRPC server after calling fork

Tags: c++, linux, ssl, fork, grpc

I am trying to make c++ `gRPC` server a daemon process by forking a child and making parent exit. But after that the client handshake starts to fail.

```
E0307 01:15:58.221786152 27094 handshake.c:128] Security handshake failed: 
{"created":"@1488878158.221756436","description":"Handshake read failed",
"file":"src/core/lib/security/transport/handshake.c",
"file_line":237,"referenced_errors":
[{"created":"@1488878158.221740996","description":"FD shutdown",
"file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll_linux.c","file_line":948}]}
```

This happens when `fork()` is called after the call to `BuildAndStart()`. If the same fork is done before `BuildAndStart()` everything works fine.
I Know nothing about underlying SSL implementation and how gRPC server behaves with keys and certificates.

Answer (score 0):

The file description corresponding to the connection is being shutdown, which results in the SSL handshake failing. The reason why the FD is being shutdown in the first place is likely due to the fact that, after a fork, both the parent and the child share the file descriptor struct in the kernel. Therefore, unless great care is exercise to synchronize the access, you'd have a data race.

If possible, try forking earlier. Otherwise, it all depends on what the parent and child do post-fork.

Comment: Forking earlier works fine. That allows the parent to exit before the child starts listening on the port. A client may try to establish connection with the server that is not ready yet. I was trying to avoid that. But, can overcome the problem by using pipes to make parent wait for the child to indicate when it is ready.

Comment: Sounds good. There's always a need to synchronize parents and children, and pipes is one way.